# what are the methods that start with two underscores and end with two underscores called in python?

Tags: python

what are the methods that start with two underscores and end with two underscores called in python? For e.g. doc , init ,etc. I am confused whether these are are termed as "special" methods/functions, or are just in-built methods/functions.

searched on google and confused between special and in-built methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of magic methods and why do we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970686/what-is-the-meaning-of-magic-methods-and-why-do-we-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

They are known as *dunder* methods. (double under). They are not necessarily built-in

Comment: don't feed the spammers / bot accounts. This same question with almost same wording has been on python tag 3-4 times in a row - all from different accounts.

Comment: @rasjani It's probably this phenomenon. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427302/recent-flood-of-very-low-quality-questions-and-non-questions-with-the-python-tag

Comment: @AKX How would mere mortals (such as me) accurately identify an account as being bot generated. In the article you referred to it's clear that moderators can "see" where an account was generated (IP address) but how do others tell?

Comment: It's not about the IP address per se, and the user is likely not a bot either, just someone unfortunate tasked to ask any Python-related question on SO. This question is just pretty low quality in itself, and the (now-)linked dupe is pretty easy to find (even with SO's abysmal search).

Comment: At the time of this post appeared on python newest, this same exact question was posted 4 times  and was clearly visible in latest 50 posts.  I guess i'm not a mare mortal and i have build in bayesian spam detection built in but I would assume someone willing to help people without ulterior motives  would spot those too. Also, Copy pasting the same exact question to google leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name  - As far as i know - anyone who is not trying to harvest internet points, can mark duplicates?